# Is this a valid regex pattern?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm trying to chuck a lot of variations in a regex pattern but I'm unsure if you can use stuff like the start of string character like this:

```
preg_match("#/str1|str2|^/str3#i",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
```

So the following should be met for the value of: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']

Contain `/str1` or `str2` or the start of the string should be `/str3`.

Comment: [check this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/)

Comment: Your regex seems to do the right thing.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Should I enclose it in parentheses at all? Such as `preg_match("#/(str1|str2|^/str3)#i",$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` - is there any difference?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Well I tested it and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regular expression should probably be:

```
preg_match('#(\/str1|str2|^\/str3)/i#', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI);
```

For a better understanding of writing expressions, Check Pankit's [link](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/).

Comment: Hm, won't that require `/str1` and `str2` to be at the start of the string?

Comment: Correct, probably misread `contains` with `starts` I think, editted the regular expression.